# NSNumberFormatter rounding incorrectly when converting NSDecimalNumber to NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnumberformatter, nsdecimalnumber

I am running the following code when attempting to calculate the amount of tax applied to a product and display it in a label.  This tax should use bankers rounding (same as `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven`)

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[formatter setRoundingMode:NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven];

NSDecimalNumber *decimalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"3.785272"];

NSLog(@" tax : %@", decimalTax);
NSString *rightText =  [formatter stringFromNumber: decimalTax];
NSLog(@" textLabel : %@", rightText);
```

This outputs the following:

```
tax : 3.785272
textLabel : $3.79
```

When using `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven`, the tax should round to 3.78, rather than 3.79.  I can't figure out why it isn't respecting the rounding mode.  I thought it might have something to do with `NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle` not playing nicely with `NSNumberFormatterRoundHalfEven`, so I changed the style to decimal and set the minimum/maximum fractional digits to 2 and it still performs exactly the same way.

I thought it might be something strange going on with `NSNumberFormatter` interacting with `NSDecimalNumber` so I tried this code instead:

```
NSDecimalNumberHandler *numberHandler = [[NSDecimalNumberHandler alloc] initWithRoundingMode:NSRoundBankers scale:2 raiseOnExactness:YES raiseOnOverflow:YES raiseOnUnderflow:YES raiseOnDivideByZero:YES];

NSDecimalNumber *decimalTax = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"3.785272"];

NSString *rightText = [[decimalTax decimalNumberByRoundingAccordingToBehavior:numberHandler] description];
```

But it still outputs the following:

```
tax : 3.785272
textLabel : 3.79
```

I am completely at a loss for ideas now.  Does anyone spot an error in what I'm doing in either of these methods? I prefer to use the first method involving NSNumberFormatter, as that would save me from doing a lot of refactoring, but if I have to use the second method to get a correct answer then so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that looks like the correct behavior to me. If you look at the documentation of RoundHalfEven it says

> Round towards the nearest integer, or towards an even number if equidistant.

In your case 3.785272 *is* closer to 3.79 than it is to 3.78, thus it is *not* equidistant and should *not* round towards an even number.

It should only round to an even number if it was *truly* equidistant, in your case 3.785 would round to 3.78.

Comment: Ahhhh that makes so much more sense.  I misread that to mean "if the digit after the one which you are rounding to is equidistant".  Meaning that 3.785272 would look at the 5, and since it is equidistant between 1 and 9, and round down to 3.78.  Thanks for clearing that up for me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
[formatter setRoundingIncrement:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:0.001]];
```

It is help me and working correctly!

Comment: I will keep that in mind if I need to change the functionality. I was trying to implement correct banker's rounding, and as the accepted comment says, this is the correct functionality for banker's rounding. I just misunderstood what was supposed to happen.